# How to use overflow-y:auto with child with bottom: 0 and position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a div with `overflow-y:auto;` and some elements, at the bottom I have a footer. The footer sticks to the bottom with: `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0px;` It works...until I decrease the height of the parent too much, then the footer is no longer at the bottom of the div. How to fix this?
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/smfg7357/2/

html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class = "inner">
    <div class= "item">item1</div>
    <div class= "item">item2</div>
    <div class= "item">item3</div>
    <div class= "item">item4</div>
    <div class= "item">item5</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer{
  background-color: lightblue; 
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.inner{

}

.item{
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item:hover{
  background-color: darkblue;
}

#footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}

#footer:hover{
  background-color: darkred;
}
```

Comment: flexbox is the ideal tool to solve stuff like this properly nowadays (and without crude hacks like absolute positioning, messing with the overflow, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to relatively position the parent element, `.inner`, so that the child `#footer` element is positioned relative to its height rather than the `.outer` element's height.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/o087fatd/)

```
.inner {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

When absolutely positioning an element, it will be positioned relative to the closest positioned ancestor element (in other words, the closest ancestor element that isn't the default `position: static`). By adding `position: relative` to the `.inner` element, the `#footer` element will be absolutely positioned at the bottom of it rather than the bottom of the `.outer` element. In addition, you can also set the `.inner` element's `min-height` to `100%` so that it will always have a minimum height equal to the height of the `.outer` element.

---

It's also worth pointing out that absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow, which means that it will overlap with your last element (in this case item 5 won't be visible). If this isn't the desired result, you could simply displace the element with padding. In this case, since the element has a fixed height of `48px`, simple add `padding-bottom: 48px` to the `.inner` element as well:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/o087fatd/)

```
.inner {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

However, you can avoid absolute positioning and utilize flexboxes. Simply set the `display` of the parent element to `flex` and then change the `flex-direction` to `column` and add `margin-top: auto` to the `.footer` element in order to position it at the bottom of the parent element.

```
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Basic example here:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item, .footer {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item">item1</div>
    <div class="item">item2</div>
    <div class="item">item3</div>
    <div class="item">item4</div>
    <div class="item">item5</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @blobliebla An absolutely positioned element is removed from the normal flow, thus it is positioned above item 5. What exactly are you trying to achieve? If the footer element is the last element, why do you need to absolutely position it at the bottom anyways?

Comment: For a left menu like this one: https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html (click on the hamburger menu to open). The footer is always on the bottom and I need something like that.

Comment: That solution doesn't work with .outer height set to something like 600px, the footer doesn't stick to the bottom

Comment: @blobliebla Then set the `min-height` of the `.inner` element to `100%`. See the updated example -> jsfiddle.net/o087fatd I also added a flexbox alternative.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thank you very much!